# Unsupported ContentType in Apache solr 4.7

Tags: eclipse, solrj

Exception in thread "main"

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: 
    Unsupported ContentType: application/octet-stream  Not in: 
             [application/xml, text/csv, text/json,application/csv, 
                  application/javabin, text/xml, application/json]
```

i am using `solr 4.7` and `eclipse 3.6`. i am getting this error for request type. can anyone help me for this error? i'll appreciate for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to succeed? Please present more info regarding your problem. Are you trying to import data to SOLR using Solrj? If so, you should specify the content type of your input stream to XML,CSV,JSON, etc.